# Resource questions left open then answers need to be allowed

Tags: discussion

[Where can I find unique templates for Presentation folders?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/where-can-i-find-unique-templates-for-presentation-folders/26062#26062)

The person is asking for resources on free folder templates and this person offered just that. I see nothing wrong with their answer. Is it their first post on here and possibly their company, yes. But stackexchange links are no-follow, and the answer only discusses the free templates and the question. So far it has 2 flags against. I would mark against those flags but my rep isn't there yet.

If we're going to leave a question of this type open then answers like the above link seem to be perfectly acceptable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two flags were for "very low quality", which I declined. VLQ is [rarely appropriate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160754/216955). That flag basically means "[this is so bad that it provides no value and needs to be deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/216955)". We are asked to exercise very light moderation when it comes to deleting things, it should only be done in extreme cases. This post, in my opinion, does not warrant deletion.

It is a link only answer, but it answers the question. Link can be lousy, but the best course of action is to downvote them if you think they serve almost no value. It could possibly be self promotion, but there is no evidence that I could see for that.

As you pointed out, external links are all no-follow on SE. So, I don't see much harm in keeping the answer around. If it will possibly be helpful to someone further down the road, I don't have a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

I flagged it because if you visit the links you have to search for the actual templates which would, to me, make it spam and appear as an advertisement.

Even though the site links to [here](http://www.companyfolders.com/design/freebies) it should really link [here](http://www.companyfolders.com/design/die-cut-folder-templates). Also what is it to say if the company goes out of business in a year and then the link becomes useless.  That is one why I do not like template request questions because it changes often.

Comment: Well I can agree with your second point, but nobody has downvoted or voted to close the question. I don't think its right to penalize the person that answers it if the question is the problem. All it needed then was for the link to be edited which I went ahead and did

Comment: You do also realize that two of the deleted answers are technically the same as the on one in question?

Comment: I thought people closed the other two because of the terrible comments such as suggesting to use MS Paint and that companies don't provide free templates not because of the links (which I didnt click on for those two)